# What are the invariant polynomials of representations of the Lorentz group $SO^+(3,1)$ and $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$?

Tags: lie-groups, mathematical-physics, invariant-theory

The Lie Groups $SO^+(3,1)$ and $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ occupy a particular, unique place in physics. I am interested in the following problem: suppose I have a finite-dimensional representation (not necessarily irreducible!) of one of these groups. How can one classify of all the invariant polynomials under this representation?

Comment: what do you mean under the invariant polynomial?

Comment: @Leox The polynomials on the vector space on which the representation is defined that are invariant under the action of the group in that representation.

Answer (score 0):

The case $SL(2)$ is the well known  problem of the classical invariant theory. You may find lists of invariants for example [here](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Eaeb/math/invar.html)